# Wordpress: Use AJAX to get the next post

Tags: ajax, wordpress, post

After looking through the jQuery documentation and many stackexchange community forums, I am still faced with this problem. Taking little bits from here and there have helped me get this far, but I am stuck where I am now.

Im using an ajax request to try and load the next post after the one that is currently displayed. The only issue I run into is when I try to execute the method included in my php file:

```
<?php

echo getnext();

function getnext(){


$post = get_post($_POST['id']);

$prevPost = get_previous_post();

return $prevPost->post_content;



}
?>
```

I can echo the POST variable that is being passed in fine, but once I try to actually call the method I get a 500 internal Server Error.

My AJAX request looks like this:

```
  setTimeout(function (){

$currid = $('#post_id').val();

$.post("wp-content/themes/stargazer/populate.php",
        {
            "id":$currid
        },
        function(data){
            //$("#academiccontent").html(data);
            alert (data);
        });

$('#academiccontent').animate({ 'opacity': 1 });

 }, 1000);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Ive been stuck on this for a long while now.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'd suggest reading this article on using AJAX with WordPress: http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use AJAX directly in WordPress?

The best way is add to function.php file in your theme something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getnext', 'getnext' );

function getnext() {
    $post = get_post($_POST['id']);
    $prevPost = get_previous_post();
    return $prevPost->post_content;
    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

And your javascript change to this:

```
setTimeout(function (){

    $currid = $('#post_id').val();
    var data = {
         "action": "getnext",
         "id":$currid
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data,   
    function(data){
        alert (data);
    });

    $('#academiccontent').animate({ 'opacity': 1 });

}, 1000);
```

More info about AJAX in WordPress you can find here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)